# Show search result and hide rest of the content

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, jsp, tiles

I use tiles and have a header,top navigation menu and body/content(all individual jsp pages). I have a search bar in header and i show the result in a div on body/content using spring and ajax. When i show the result i want to hide the rest of the contents on that page. Any help please.

On header

```
<div>
<form id="searchForm" action="searchproduct.json" > 
    Product Name: <input type="text" name="productName" value="${product.productName}"
                     id="productName"  />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
</div>
```

another JSP

```
    <div id="formResponse">
    <table id="searchTable">
    </table>
    </div>
<div>
//other contents
</div>
```

Comment: so whats is the problem here ? where you are stucked

Comment: show some more codes , it will be very helpful

Comment: In jSP or any other thing

Comment: it will be better with Jquery , since you are using AJAX

Comment: use `$('#idOfElement').hide();` or `$('.classOfElements').hide()`

Comment: @ lolka_bolka  I want to hide in all the pages. i have to add all the id or class ??